# Looping through multidimensional array in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

please let me know if you have any suggestions whatsoever as I am completely stuck on this! Really need any help. Let me know if I can make anything more clear!

My Model:

**Query #1** -- Retrieves list of CampaignIds from the session

```
public function retrieve_campaign($CompanyId)
    {   
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('Campaign');
            $this->db->join('Product', 'Campaign.ProductId=Product.ProductId');
            $this->db->where('Product.CompanyId', $CompanyId); 
            $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query->result_array(); 
    }
```

**Query #2** -- Collects number of hits on a website per day

```
    public function week_data($i, $CampaignId, $StartDate) {
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount 
            FROM Record 
            WHERE CampaignId = ' . $CampaignId . ' 
            AND DATE(TimeStamp) = ' . $StartDate . ' + interval ' . $i . ' day');
        return $query;
    }
```

My Controller:
As you can see, I set the session data, plug it into query #1.
That data is then used in a foreach loop to query #2 seven times (one for each day of the week). This data is then stored in an array $data['test']

```
public function index()
{   
    // Set Session Varaible
    $CompanyId = $this->session->userdata('CompanyId'); 
    $StartDate = "'2014-06-23'";

    // Assign query result to array  to be used in view
    $data['campaigns'] = $this->model_record->retrieve_campaign($CompanyId);

    foreach($data['campaigns'] as $item) {
        for($x = 0;$x > 6;$x++) {
            echo $item['CampaignId'];
            $data['test'] = $this->model_record->week_data($x,$item,$StartDate);
        }
    }

    // Load views, pass query result array
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('dashboard/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

My View: Here is where I am having trouble-- I would like to loop through the CampaignId's echoing them, then echo all the associated data from query #2 that relates to that CampaignId.

**Example:**

1) Retrieve CampaignIds, query each CampaignId 7 times for each day of the week, then print something on the view similar to this:

CampaignId: 1
Web Hits: 55,63,32,39,22,33,61

etc...

PLEASE suggestions will help, I have been working on this for 3 days now and hit a wall.
Thank you SO much all!

---

EDIT

Thank you so much to Scrowler--helping me through every step. Working EDIT:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{   
    // Set Session Varaible
    $CompanyId = $this->session->userdata('CompanyId'); 
    $StartDate = "'2014-06-23'";

    // Assign query result to array  to be used in view
    $data['campaigns'] = $this->model_record->retrieve_campaign($CompanyId);

    foreach($data['campaigns'] as $item) {
        for($x = 0; $x < 7; $x++) {
            $data['CampaignData'][$item['CampaignId']][] = $this->model_record->week_data($x, $item['CampaignId'], $StartDate);
        }
    }
    // Load views, pass query result array
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('dashboard/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

View:

```
<?php 
foreach($CampaignData as $campaign_id => $week_data) {
    echo 'Campaign: ' . $campaign_id . ', web hits: ' . implode(', ', $week_data) . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you not just put your `echo $item['CampaignId'];` before the `for` loop then echo the results of `$data['test']` after you've retrieve it in each iteration?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot echo in the controller. The data must be placed back into the $data[''] array to be carried over to the view

Comment: Right, so add it to an array and use CampaignId as the key: `$data['CampaignData'][$item['CampaignId']][] = $this->model_record->week_data($x, $item, $StartDate);`

Comment: Thank you so much scrowler, that really helped. I've updated my post for my current question--I'm not sure how to format the forloop to display my information on the view

Answer (score 1):

You can add your week data to an array during your `for` loop, identified by the campaign ID as the array key, then pass that to your view:

```
foreach($data['campaigns'] as $item) {
    for($x = 0; $x < 7; $x++) {
        $data['CampaignData'][$item['CampaignId']][] = $this->model_record->week_data($x, $item, $StartDate);
    }
}
```

Then you can output your data like this:

```
foreach($data['CampaignData'] as $campaign_id => $week_data) {
    echo 'Campaign: ' . $campaign_id . ', web hits: ' . implode(', ', $week_data) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You can of course format your output better than that, but that example should give you what you want, e.g.:

> Campaign: 1, web hits: 55, 63, 32, 39, 22, 33, 61

Comment: I cannot begin to thank you both enough. This has been so insightful for me. Unfortunately, I changed my code to your suggestion, however, I am receiving a Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and Message: Undefined variable: data

Comment: You'll need to change that `$data` variable to reflect the variable name in the CodeIgniter view (is it `$CampaignData`?) I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter

Comment: It Works! An oversight on my part -- will update with the full edited code. Thank you so much! I think I may cry.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop statement looks incorrect. If you want to loop 7 times, change it to

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++)
```

Your final code should probably look like this

```
foreach($data['campaigns'] as $item) {
    $data[$item['CampaignId']] = array();
    for($x = 0;$x <= 6;$x++) {
        $data[$item['CampaignId']][] = $this->model_record->week_data($x,$item,$StartDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will give you 8 repetitions - swap `<=` for `<` to get seven days, or start `$x` at one instead of zero